# Minimizing the expectation value of least-squares loss when data and model are randomly distributed with known normal distribution

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, linear-model, heteroscedasticity

How do you minimize the stochastic robust least-squares problem
$$
\min_x \mathbb{E}\left\{||A x - b||^2\right\}
$$
in which both the parameters $b$ and the model $A$ are normally distributed with known mean and covariance, that is,
$
vec([A; b]) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)
$ ?

Comment: The way this question is written, this is not a least squares problem. Are you sure it is not $\| Ax-b\|^2$? Also, the phrase  "the expectation value of a stochastic least squares problem" is awkward.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the question. In the deterministic case $\arg\min ||Ax-b|| = \arg\min ||Ax-b||^2$ but that is not true here, I guess.

Comment: No matter what $\Sigma$ may be--indeed, not matter what the distribution of $(A,b)$ is--the expectation (if it exists, which it does in the Normal case) is (still) a quadratic form in $x,$ making this a (standard) least-squares problem.

Comment: I used "stochastic" here to differentiate from the standard form of linear least-squares. What would be a better description? Also, it is not obvious to me how to compute the expectation value to get to the quadratic form in $x$. How does one compute the expectation value of $A^TA$ and $A^Tb$ with the covariance given in the form above?